# How can I add a line connecting the Mean in ggline, R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Hi All I am producing this plot with ggline (code below) I was wondering if there is a way to put a line that connect the mean.

```
ggline(My_table2, x = "Status", y = "Ratio", 
       color = "Status",
       order = c("Non_Treated", "Disease1", "Disease2"),  ggtheme=theme_gray(),
       ylab = "Ratio", xlab = "Status",
       add="mean_se",palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
       font.label = list(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10))+theme_bw(base_size = 30)
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried changing the group ? Default is "1", meaning one line per group. ggline might misunderstand this here

Comment: @tjebo I will try it now, It give me this error, geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with slightly lower level packages - in this case ggplot2 is I think much easier. I think also less code. I am modifying the iris data set because it seems to resemble your data. I am creating a group for the entire data and using this for the line. And quite non-elegantly using stat_summary twice.

```r
library(ggplot2)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$all <- 1

ggplot(iris2, aes(Species, Sepal.Length )) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = Species)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", aes(group = all))
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>